# Lucene.NET and external sites

Tags: search, indexing, lucene.net

We have built a web site which employs Lucene.NET for search. We recently have integrated another web site so that form a user's perspective both website seem to be just one site! (we share the mater pages, etc.)

The problem we have is that two web sites are hosted in different locations. So when Lucene.NET crawls the first web site, it does not pick the content of the second web site. We want to extract the content from the 2nd web site and put it in the same index file that is built for the first site.

How can I get Lucene.NET to crawl an external site too?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have file-system access to the 2nd system than you can just index by providing the path. If not, you will need to write a crawler, you can start with something basic using HttpWebRequest, or get fancier by using [some tools](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=.net%20crawler%20web&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=4fc1c984211b8d1b&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1600&bih=743) that recursively crawl a site using links etc.